# matlab selecting regions in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, mouse, regions

I have a problem when i am working with plots in Matlab. Following are my issues with Plots:

- How can one select Regions after plotting data using mouse?
- After selecting the Regions how to get data from that region?

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what your plots look like or what kind of regions you want to define so I can't offer any specific instructions. Try looking into the ginput function.

Comment: my plot have some quadratic curves. ginput just gives selected data, but when i have my plot i need to be able to select some zone or region using mouse like using mouse drag two horizontal line, area between those lines would be a region.

Comment: ginput gives the (x,y) coordinate of where you clicked. You could, for example, use two clicks (i.e. [x,y]=ginput(2)) to define the top left and bottom right corners of a rectangle, and use everything in that rectangle as your region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting regions with a mouse is quite easy using the rbbox function.

First you add a ButtonDownFcn to the axes you are drawing rbbox on.

```
hax = axes( ... , 'ButtonDownFcn', @OnClickAxes);
```

Then you call rbbox within the callback like this

```
function OnClickAxes( hax, evt )

point1 = get(hax,'CurrentPoint'); % hax is handle to axes
rbbox;
point2 = get(hax,'CurrentPoint'); % hax is handle to axes

end
```

Here point1 and point2 will define the two corners of the rectangle drawn by your mouse in data coordinates.  Type **doc rbbox** at matlab prompt for more information

Now to answer your second question for 2-D plots.

This bit of code will extract and return the data within the selected region for all lines within an axes.

https://gist.github.com/3107790